# Insert a converted Php array in a js object

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, object

I have a php array that i converted in Js using the json_encode method:

```
$mesi = ['Nov', 'Dic'];

var js_mesi = '<?php print(json_encode($mesi)); ?>';
```

this is the converted array

```
["Nov","Dic"]
```

The problem I'm having now it's to place the Js array inside a JS object like this

```
data: {
    labels: [js_mesi],
}
```

because the values of js_mesi are recognized as a single value and not as two separate values. The output I would like to have is this:

```
data: {
    labels: ["Nov", "Dic"]
}
```

instead I see this

```
data: {
    labels: ["Nov,Dic"]
}
```

Comment: What you say you see does not match what you say you're doing in code.

Comment: Why does this question look exactly like another question I just saw a half hour ago that was deleted.

Comment: Can I please understand why someone downvoted the question? The question it's pretty clare and easy. I thought this forum was made to help people and not to place randomly stupid vote.

Comment: Because no one helped me so I wrote again the question in a easier way. I have a problem and I would like to solve it

Comment: It's incredible how many people are on this forum just to downvote question instead of giving an usefull help.

Comment: You appear to already know how to encode and output a php array as a js array. The step you are missing how to set a js array as a value in an object. Which, while bit a duplicate of any question I can find on this site, is a basic step in programming js. (I haven't downvoted btw)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the javascript variable assignment, you had added `'` single quotes around the PHP block.

Hence it was considered as a string and would have got the value `'["Nov","Dic"]'` instead of an array.

**Corrected code**

```
<?php
$mesi = array('Nov','Dic');
?>

var js_mesi = <?php print(json_encode($mesi)); ?>;
```

**Output**

```
var js_mesi = ["Nov","Dic"];
```

Refer https://eval.in/920653 for the output